# chef deployment suggestions/scenerio

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

quick one .How would you suggest to deploy chef system . Basically we are 3 engineers in our team. We are looking to deploy chef to manage a  combination of both ubuntu and redhat servers. Chef-server is setup and running. I am a bit confused on the below question

1.) How do we setup chef-workstations for each engineer to be able to write and manage a single cookbook or do we write our separate cookbooks?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, but a fairly standard way to use chef would be for each developer to use their workstation to access the chef-server and apply shared cookbooks to a variety of nodes (the ubuntu and redhat servers in your example). The chef-server would store the shared cookbooks, although you may want to have them in version-control too. No need for seperate cookbooks.

Comment: Hi disco 3 ,sure ur answer is quite helpful . Never knew about the concept of  "Shared cookbooks" for nodes. Will go on to google my days on that .However if you have a good link on that ,kindly drop me a message on the post...Though not sure on the version control bit to integrate everything together , but yeap will look around as well, thanks .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, but a fairly standard way to use chef would be for each developer to use their workstation to access the chef-server and apply shared cookbooks to a variety of nodes (the ubuntu and redhat servers in your example). The chef-server would store the shared cookbooks, although you may want to have them in version-control too. No need for seperate cookbooks.

See https://learn.chef.io/manage-a-node/ubuntu/

The Chef docs at https://learn.chef.io/ are quite comprehensive, as is the O'Reilly book Learning Chef